# Option for deletion not available in Low Quality Posts review queue

Tags: support, review-queues, comments, low-quality-posts

While reviewing in the Low Quality Posts queue I came across some questions which have the following comment from other users (probably from the review queue):

> While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

I can't see this option anywhere in the options that are available to me in the review; I only have following options available:

[image: Review List]

Why is this different?

Comment: The regulars of the SOCVR room maintain a list of so-called [auto-comments](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments)

Comment: There's the "no comments needed" option, if the comment is already included and you agree with the action being taken

Comment: @Braiam problem is deleting those answer is not the best choice as they may contain correct answer, they lack explanation

Comment: How it's not? If there's an answer that not only has the correct answer but also the explanation, why should we keep *two answers*?

Comment: @braiam because the LQPRQ is not about determining what content should be deleted, it is about determining whether or not posts were flagged correctly. Just because you see an answer that you don't like in there doesn't mean that it should be deleted through the queue. Search for "You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the low quality posts queue" for more on why you shouldnt abuse the delete button in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

is *not* an option in the Low Quality Posts review queue. Standard comments from Review (at least those from the last couple of months) have a [From Review] link at the end.

It's posted by somebody from *outside* the review queue, probably using a 'pro-forma comment' - there is a [userscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments) for that.

Comment: so to use this we have to copy paste it from the site or something else?

Comment: Yes, copy-paste or use the userscript. They're not provided by Stack Overflow in any way.

Comment: Thanks but If would not have to use comments from userscript what would be the best option for these types of answers as the code may be useful so deleting them will not be good

Comment: Well, then you just have to type the comment yourself. Remember that code snippets without explanation should be *down*voted, but not necessarily *deleted*. They might have *some* use after all.